# When software updated show warning message "package operation failed" in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, updates, update-manager, source-packages

Package operation failed  in Ubuntu 16.04.

[image: Software Updater problem screenshot]

Comment: What package? What were you doing? Did you try the command line?

Comment: How to command line use for package update ?

Comment: Please open a terminal (CTRL+ALT+T) and type the command `sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get upgrade`. Then [edit] your question and paste the output of those commands. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Failsafe method of upgrading your packages:
Open a Terminal window and type:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Installing a package:

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install packagename
```

Removing a package:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get remove packagename
```

**Always** use : `sudo apt-get update` **before** any maintenance command , otherwise erorrs like yours might occur.